# Popper.js overlays the input field label

Tags: material-ui, popper.js

Popper.js overlays `material-ui` input field if the placement is flipping to the `top`. How avoid the overlaying?

The popper code:

```
<Popper
   id={id}
   open={open}
   anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
   style={{ zIndex: 13001 }}
   disablePortal={true}
   modifiers={{
     name: 'preventOverflow',
      options: {
        padding: 0,
       },
     }}
 >
  {children elements} 
</Popper>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, use a greater `z-index` property for the field label and a less `z-index` for the `Popper` element.